# How to implement doNothing() for static void method?

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, powermockito, springmockito

Am trying to mock one static void method, I tried PowerMock but always getting NullPointer exception.

We are trying to mock the below call -

```
public Class XYZ{
  public void method1(){
     ....
     SampleClass.methodTypeStatic1().methodTypeStatic2("xyz", "mno", classVeriable);
}
```

And the main class is -

```
public class SampleClass implements SampleClassParent{

private static SampleClass var1;

public static SampleClass methodTypeStatic1(){
    if (var1 == null) {
        //Do something on var1
    }
    return var1;
}

public void methodTypeStatic2(String localVar1, String localVar2, DifferentStaticClass localVar3) {
    //Do something
}}
```

Am trying to mock the call like this way in my test class -

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({SampleClass.class})
public class XYZTest{

   @InjectMocks
   XYZ xyzTestService;

   @Test
   public void testMethod1(){
     ...
     PowerMockito.mockStatic(SampleClass.class);
     PowerMockito.doNothing().when(SampleClass.methodTypeStatic1());
     xyzTestService.method1();
}
```

Also to be mentioned SampleClass.class is not a part of our code, we have imported this external class into our code base to perform some task.

Comment: Please add your complete UnitTest and the related stacktrace.

Comment: Question is updated as requested.

Comment: What you added isn't a complete and runnable unit test. What annotations do you use?

Comment: Annotate test class with @PrepareforTest(SampleClass.class) then try

Comment: @second I have added the full test now.

Comment: var1 is null by default that's the reason why you are getting NPE, use reflection to inject field value

Comment: and one more thing is methodTypeStatic1 is not void, you're not supposed to use doNothing on non-void methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mock a non-void method, you need to define the behaviour for this method on the mock. You get the `doNothing` for free (as this is what mocking does),
however you need to define what the method is supposed to return.

Your test could look like this:

```
@Test
public void testMethod1() {

    SampleClass sample = new SampleClass();

    PowerMockito.mockStatic(SampleClass.class);
    PowerMockito.when(SampleClass.methodTypeStatic1()).thenReturn(sample);

    XYZ xyzTestService = new XYZ();
    xyzTestService.method1();
}
```

You didn't not mention any `@Mock` annotations, so using `@InjectMocks` does nothing for you besides creating the `XYZ` object.